# Why is this for loop looping through the array 4 times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am testing an array against some characters, I am wondering why it is looping through the array 4 times. I am just trying to loop through `toTest` once. Here is the code and a fiddle

```
var testAgainst = ['and','+',',','&'];
var toTest = ["$ Red Arcane Playing Cards Deck Ellusionist Rare New Sealed $", "Ellusionist Red Arcane Deck - Very Rare - Playing Cards - Magic Tricks- New", "24 HR Sale! Red and White LTD & Red Arcane Playing Cards Ellusionist near mint", "4x Arcane Playing Cards Deck Collection Rare Gold Red + Black White Ellusionist", "Red Arcane Playing Cards by Ellusionist", "24 HR SALE Red Arcane Playing Cards by Ellusionist", "RED ARCANE PLAYING CARDS", "Ellusionist - New/Sealed Red Arcane Playing cards c.2013 - Rare deck"];

for(var i = 0; i < testAgainst.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < toTest.length; j++){
        if (toTest[j].indexOf(testAgainst[i]) > -1){
            console.log('match: ' + toTest[j]);
        }else{
            console.log('no match ' + toTest[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bmpgsxb2/4/

Why is it looping through so much?

**Thanks to all who pointed me in the right direction. I should have realized that is what was going on. After playing around with it for a while I came up with this, which only filters the data once and splits the data up depending on if it meets the criteria or not**

**JSFIDDLE UPDATE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bmpgsxb2/7/

Comment: Don't you forgot a break statement in your code?

Comment: Because testAgainst has 4 items in it?

Comment: Because you have two nested loops and you're looping through `toTest` as many times as you have items in `testAgain`...!?

Comment: You're looping through testAgainst. For every element in testAgainst you'll do a complete loop through toTest.

Comment: Maybe it is gettimg mor clear when you swap the two 'for' statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write a `for` loop from `testAgainst` and `testAgainst.length === 4` that's why it loops 4 times on `toTest`

You algorithm is good. I don't see any other possibilities, maybe by using regexp but it depends what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is in another loop which runs `testAgainst.length` times (which is 4).

```
for(var i = 0; i < testAgainst.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < toTest.length; j++){
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly iterating `testAgainst.length` * `toTest.length` times, which is 4 * 8 times = 32.

Answer (score 0):

Your algo is good, it can be more optimized when you run outer loop toTest.length and inner loop to testAgainst.length so that once testAgainst keyword found ,then match found , no need to iterate more, also put `break` statement in if loop.